# Dropping from external .py into jupyter notebook

Tags: python, ipython, jupyter-notebook

My motivation here is to develop new functions that should live in external modules, and I'd like to use a jupyter notebook for interactive development.

Is there a way to set a breakpoint or similar in an external .py file that will let me export the current namespace right back to the jupyter notebook, so code in another cell can run within the scope of the breakpoint?

I've tried using pdb etc. but I want something more along the lines of code.interact(), but that lets me then use the full features of a jupyter notebook.